# A variable cannot be exported in a vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

"vue": "2.5.2",
"vue-loader": "15.4.2",
"webpack": "4.26.1",

```js
// A.vue
export let a = 1
export default {
  name: 'a',
  data()(),
}

// B.vue
import A, { a } from './A.vue'
```

import A successfully;

But: "export 'a' was not found in './A.vue'

Answer (score 0):

It must be because a `let` variable only works in the scope where is declared, try with a `const` as in:

```js
export const a = 1
```

Comment: The question remains.

Comment: maybe is also beacause you are using a .vue file instead of .js i don't see any template...

Answer (score -1):

In ES6, `export default` is to export a single value (or function). If you need to export several things from your module, use named exports. [Check the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export)

```
export A {
  name: 'a',
  data()(),
}
export let a=2

///in B.vue
import {A, a} from './A.vue'
```

I'm not sure that's the best approach though, I guess a Vue component should only export the component itself. And if you need another value, create a different module in a .js file somewhere. And if you need to share state between your components, use VueX instead.